# AddNot in condition in yii

Tags: yii

How to write AddNotin condition in Join Query in Criteria,

```
public function assigned()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;                              
    $criteria->addCondition("t.tile_id <> (INNER JOIN `tbl_user_tile` AS `pr` ON pr.tile_id = t.tile_id");                
    $criteria->compare('deleted_by',$this->deleted_by,true);
    $criteria->compare('deleted_date',$this->deleted_date,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

I want to return not match record Its not working What wrong in my code?
I want to take first table record without match in second table record.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got output,

```
public function assigned()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

            $classes = Question::model()->findAll(array(   
'join' => 'INNER JOIN `tbl_user_tile` AS `pr` ON pr.tile_id = t.tile_id'));


            $classarray =   "";
            for($i=0;$i<count($classes);$i++)
            {
            $classarray .= $classes[$i]['tile_id'].",";                
            }

            $classarray    = rtrim($classarray,',');               
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

            $criteria->addCondition("t.tile_id  not in (" . $classarray . ")");     

    $criteria->compare('deleted_by',$this->deleted_by,true);
    $criteria->compare('deleted_date',$this->deleted_date,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query as follows:

```
public function assigned()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->join = "LEFT JOIN `tbl_user_tile` AS `pr` ON pr.tile_id = t.tile_id";
    $criteria->condition = "pr.tile_id IS NULL";

    $criteria->compare('deleted_by',$this->deleted_by,true);
    $criteria->compare('deleted_date',$this->deleted_date,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know in case of any concerns.